# Google Chart vAxis.format big numbers 10^30

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I've built a google chart and got really big numbers, 10^30 and higher.
How do I format them so that users can understand something?

I already built a function:

```
console.log(bigNum(1000000000));
```

gives me *1 billion*.
Is it even possible to use own functions?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `vAxis.format` option to do this, but you can specify your own axis tick marks and labels using the `vAxis.ticks` option:

```
// create array of tick mark objects for values 0 to 10 billion every 1 billion
var ticks = [], val;
for (var i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    val = i * 1000000000;
    ticks.push({v: val, f: bigNum(val)});
}
```

and then in the chart options:

```
vAxis: {
    ticks: ticks
}
```